# when load Assets?

Tags: android, libgdx

what is the best way?

1) make a method:

```
Assets.loadAll()
```

that load all the texture used in the game, and call this method in the splashScreen (so    only one time in all the activity life)

OR

2) make one method for each screen (ie. Assets.loadMainMenu, Assets.loadGameScreen, etc..) and call it in the show() of any screen? (and in the hide() call the Assets.disposeMainMenuAssets, Assets.disposeGameScreenAssets, etc etc..)

NOTE: the 2) is slower than the first but in in the first if i block the phone (with classical phisical button) and after go back to the app, the texture disappear   (it doesn't happen if i press the 'home' button... but if i lock the phone yes.... and the strange thing is that in libGdx 9.6 if i lock the phone the textures don't disappear, but with libGdx 9.7 this append..)

Comment: depends on the amount of RAM you have and the size of the assets, i guess

Comment: I have almost 5mb of assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's 5MB's of assets I say just load them on the splash screen. That way there will be little to no "load" time between screen switching. Method 1 is the best for this.

Create a class called `Assets`. In this have a static method called "load", like so

public class Assets {

```
private static Texture tex;
public static TextureRegion tree,cloud1,cloud2,cloud3,rock,platform,playerStanding,
                            rocket, rocketShadow, moon, star;
public static SpriteAnimation playerMoving;

public static void load(){
    tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Graphics.png"));
    tex.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    tree = new TextureRegion(tex, 0,0,246,226);
    cloud1 = new TextureRegion(tex, 246,0,225,92);
    cloud2 = new TextureRegion(tex, 358,197,88,84);
    cloud3 = new TextureRegion(tex, 0,226,105,64);
    rock = new TextureRegion(tex, 246,197,112,90);
    platform = new TextureRegion(tex, 246,92,193,105);

    tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Graphics2.png"));
    tex.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    playerMoving = new SpriteAnimation(new TextureRegion(tex,0,0,458,555), 4, 5, 0.01f);
    playerStanding = new TextureRegion(tex,0,0,112,110);

    tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Graphics3.png"));
    tex.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    rocket = new TextureRegion(tex,0,218,119,201);
    rocketShadow = new TextureRegion(tex,0,0,138,218);

    tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/Graphics4.png"));
    tex.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    moon = new TextureRegion(tex,0,0,410,382);
    star = new TextureRegion(tex,0,382,123,123);
}

public static void dispose(){
    tex.dispose();
}
}
```

(This is just an example from my game. The names aren't important, just the methods)

On your splash screen you can just call `Assets.load();` and all your assets will be loaded!

Then you want to use an asset you can just make a call to it via `Assets.whatever` (which being static is fine)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Could you click the green tick next to my answer to mark the question as answered please!

Comment: i already use a class like your :-)

but if i lock the phone, when i wake-up the program, the assets dosn't load becouse it doesn't return on the spash screen, Am i right?

Comment: it wasn't me, who asked a question :)

Comment: Are you loading them as normal textures as the internal asset manager should just reload them. Or are you managing them yourself loading them into Pixmaps?

Comment: I did the same like you.. but for an unknown reason, when I wake-up the program it restarts form the splash-screen and not from the screen where i left it